# asp.net mvc Fixed header and footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

what ideal mode to fixed header and footer in layout

I must create a special view to the two right?

how declare where they will appear?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>

@RenderBody()

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use css to define where the `div` tag appears

```
#header {
   display:block;
}

#fooder {
  display: block;
}
```

might be a basic example of ensuring that the `header` is above the "body" content, and that the `footer` is below the content that came before it.  This is just a very simple, probably useless example, but it hopefully will give you the idea of where to look in your project.